# Web api and tableView problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asp.net-web-api

I am very new at Objective C and Xcode but I am learning a little bit every day!:)
I am trying to build an application that will show a webb api in my tableview, but it does not show.. when I NSLog it, it shows that my search worked and that it got the data i was looking for but it will not show in my tableView unfortunately..

If someone as time to look at the code and try to figure out what is wrong that would be great, or if someone hade a similar problem, just throw it out there so i can check if i did the same thing:)

**Best regards. Filip**

(Sorry for my bad english, I`m from Sweden and in a hurry..)

**- my .m file**

```
#import "FoodTableViewController.h"

@interface FoodTableViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property(nonatomic)NSMutableArray *foodNames;
@end

@implementation FoodTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.foodNames = [@[]mutableCopy];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchbar
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://matapi.se/foodstuff?query=%@",self.searchBar.text];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];


    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSError *parseError;

        NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&parseError];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            for(int i=0;i<json.count;i++){


                NSString *foodName = json[i][@"name"];

                [self.foodNames addObject:foodName];
                NSLog(@"Added: %@",foodName);
                NSLog(@"FOODLIST LENGTH: %d",self.foodNames.count);

            }

        });

    }];


    [task resume];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.foodNames.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(self.foodNames[indexPath.row]){
        NSLog(@"Cell text %@",self.foodNames[indexPath.row]);
        cell.textLabel.text = self.foodNames[indexPath.row];
    }else{
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading..";
    }


    return cell;
}
@end
```

**- my .h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FoodTableViewController : UITableViewController<UISearchBarDelegate>

@end
```

Comment: Note that `[NSMutableArray new]` is probably more legible than `[@[] mutableCopy]`

Answer (score 0):

`dataTaskWithRequest:...` is an asynchronous method, which means that the results are not available at the time of your `reloadData` call.  You'll need to add that call after all your data is added to the array.  In part...

```
        for(int i=0;i<json.count;i++){


            NSString *foodName = json[i][@"name"];

            [self.foodNames addObject:foodName];
            NSLog(@"Added: %@",foodName);
            NSLog(@"FOODLIST LENGTH: %d",self.foodNames.count);

        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: hi David! thank you very much for taking time to help me! I understand the problem you are pointing out, but Im not sure how i should fix it, should i change place on these two, or should I add additional code to it? Best regards. Filip

Comment: The one you have there now isn't really doing much for you, so yeah, moving it would work.

Comment: ah okey, just these lines of code?, further down where i can call after my data?                                                             `for(int i=0;i<json.count;i++){


            NSString *foodName = json[i][@"name"];

            [self.foodNames addObject:foodName];
            NSLog(@"Added: %@",foodName);
            NSLog(@"FOODLIST LENGTH: %d",self.foodNames.count);

        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];`